# Displaying tiles in the correct order using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, microsoft-metro, tiles

I am trying to obtain this result inside a div container on a empty webpage. [image: result I'm trying to obtain]

So far I've ended up with this: [image]
Which is far from what I'm aiming to obtain. I don't quite understand how elements (or containers I guess in this example) are placed on the page, or how I could display them in the way I want. Of course, I could use absolute positions and dimensions, but I need it to be 'flexible' for different resolutions, and I need to do some animations with jQuery later on involving position and size changes to each tile. Here's the structure of the page so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" id="body-wrapper">
            <div id="menu-wrapper">
                <div id="menu-area">
                    <a href="#mat1">
                        <span class="me medium_box" id="mat1">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#mat2">
                        <span class="me large_rectangle" id="mat2">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#mat3">
                        <span class="me medium_rectangle" id="mat3">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#mat4">
                        <span class="me small_box" id="mat4">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#mat5">
                        <span class="me large_rectangle" id="mat5">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#mat6">
                        <span class="me vertical_medium_rectangle" id="mat6">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the stylesheet (style.css):

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #41B1E1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu-wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.me {
    color: white;
}

.small_box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: white;
}

.medium_box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
}

.large_rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 375px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.medium_rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}

.vertical_medium_rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
}

#menu-area {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    margin-top: 10%;
} 

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mat1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#mat2 {
    float: left;
}

#mat3 {

}
```

Comment: 1. Why don't you use a plugin for this? 2. Should use flexbox instead of inline-boxes and float. It's impossible to achieve the way you try to. Read up about flexbox in CSS.

Comment: Well I don't know what plugin you're referring to or what you meant, also I don't know what flexboxes are. I don't have a lot of experience in this field, I'm still pretty much a beginner :/

edit: will check out flexboxes, thanks.

Comment: Just google "jquery plugin tiles" and you'll be probably able to find one.

I know for sure that Angular Material has tiles component which should work similarly to what you try to achieve but it's way too big dependency to include only for this menu.

Comment: If everything has fixed sizes here, as it seems it has, you should be able also to simply use `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

I set up jsfiddle so you can see how `position: absolute` works in this case. You should be able to proceed from this point.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdfxnfba/